# How to draw a curved and gradient colored trapezoid with HTML and css3

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, css-shapes

How to draw a curved and gradient colored trapezoid with HTML and css3 like attached image.

[image]

I have this code.

```css
#trapezoid {
 height: 0;
 width: 120px;
 border-bottom: 80px solid #05ed08;
 border-left: 45px solid transparent;
 border-right: 45px solid transparent;
 padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid">Trapezoid</div>
```

Comment: Please provide you code so we can help you

Comment: I Just added my code, but it showing without curves

Comment: you want this in canvas or just using css?

Comment: Anything is ok, but result should be exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SVG` is the recommended way to create such shapes. It offers simplicity and scale ability.

The idea is to create a curve and stroke(outline) it with a gradient. We can use `SVG`'s `path` element to create the curve.

Only one attribute `d` is used to define shapes in `path` element. This attribute itself contains a number of short commands and few parameters that are necessary for those commands to work.

Below is the necessary code to create this shape:

```
<defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#e20016" />
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ed6f1d" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path d="M30,75 Q100,20 170,75" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-width="90" fill="none" />
```

I've used 2 commands inside `path` element. Below is a brief description:

- `M` command is used to define the starting point. It appears at the beginning and specify the point from where drawing should start.
- `Q` command is used to draw curves.
- `defs` element is used to define element / objects for later use in `SVG` document.
- `linearGradient` element is used to define gradients that can be applied to any shape or outline in `SVG` document.

**Output:**

[image: Output Image]

**Working Example:**

```html
<svg width="200" height="150" viewBox="0 0 200 150">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="gradient">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#e20016" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#ed6f1d" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d="M30,75 Q100,20 170,75" stroke="url(#gradient)" stroke-width="90" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
.top {
 background: #c02425;
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c02425, #f0cb35);
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #c02425, #f0cb35);
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 253px;
 height: 90px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 16px #fff, inset 0px 16px 1px 1px #fff;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 16px #999, inset 0px 16px 1px 1px #999;
 transform: rotateX(180deg);
 position: absolute;
 top: 63px;
 left: -4px;
}
.middle {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #c02425; /* fallback for old browsers */
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #c02425, #f0cb35); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
 background: linear-gradient(to right, #c02425, #f0cb35);
 transform: perspective(9px) rotateX(179deg);
 margin: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 left: -127px;
 top: -27px;
}
div#trapezoid {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
}
.bottom {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    bottom: -11%;
    left: -13px;
    border: 136px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border-bottom: 27px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="trapezoid">
<div class="top"></div>
  <div class="middle">
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't see any gradient, and the top radius is not a match